# How to restrict zoom of webpage to stretch when iPhone and Android in landscape orientation?

Tags: iphone, android, html, css, mobile-safari

How to restrict zoom of webpage to stretch when iPhone and Android in landscape orientation?

When I rotate the iphone into landscape orientation, the header takes 30% space on the screen but in Portrait mode it only takes 15 %.

Will I have to write different css for some elements in landscape orientation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the viewport meta tag, [as described by Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag). The [Apple Documentation for developing web content for iPad](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2010/tn2262/_index.html) describes this tag quite nicely too. Apple recommends:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

**EDIT:**

In your case, you can try this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, width=device-width;">
```

You can try to use [the technique mentioned here](http://www.cloudfour.com/ipad-orientation-css/), to use different stylesheets for different orientations.

Comment: I'm already using this `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0;">`

Comment: I used this `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` but this doubled the zoom then previous

Comment: Last link in answer is dead - *"404 | Page not found"*.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the webkit css

```
body {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
}
```

It basically stops the font size being adjusted when you go in to landscape.

Use with care, because if you let this css be read by a desktop safari client then it'll block any user zooming attempt from affecting font sizes.